# How to express range completely in terms of variables in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

If i wan to express range completely in terms of variables, what is the correct way to do it given then locationcolletter and lastcolletter is the column letter and extractedno and locationrowno is the row number and i wanted to express it using colon?(Eg: sheets(1).range("B5:J12").select ) but now in terms of variables.

```
Dim locationcolletter As String

Dim lastcolletter As String

Dim extractedno As Long

Dim locationrowno As Long

With Selection
    Sheets(1).Range(locationcolletter & locationrowno & ":" & lastcolletter & extractedno).Select 
'^ Is this way of expressing range with variables correct?
end with
```

Comment: looks ok to me (other than you not assigning any values to them, and something that proves you arent using zero as the row number) - Did you bother trying it to see? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @braX the question that im asking is actually a reference from this post that i made earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004244/how-to-select-a-specific-range-with-reference-from-other-points-using-vba where i got select method range of class fail at this line so i doubt i might express the range wrong here

Comment: Use `MsgBox locationcolletter & locationrowno & ":" & lastcolletter & extractedno` and see what you get. Does it look right?

Comment: @braX yeah i got B5:J12 which is what i want at the msgbox but why it shows the range of class fail error?

Comment: @braX ah my bad i think i found out where my error is, i forgot to change sheets(1) to sheets(4)..

Comment: @braX anyways thanks for the clarification

Comment: Aren't you missing the opening and closing double quotes inside the `Range()`?

Comment: @teylyn somehow it works fine without them when expressing completely in terms of variables though..